# How to link Google Sheet (range of cells) to a slide from API V4 PHP?

Tags: php, google-sheets-api, google-slides-api

I am trying to insert (link) a cell range from a Google Sheet in to a Google Slide using API V4 (PHP).

I cannot find anything in the documentation regarding this. But it is possible manually.

Is there any way to do this via API?

Comment: Reading sheets data is possible when you refer to the [text merging example](https://developers.google.com/slides/how-tos/merge#text_merging). I may suggest you can make the link from the specified cell then you can put it in other sheets where the slide can read it since the slide api will be able to fetch the data from other docs as text. If you needed some knowledge to make a link, you can refer to the [StackExchange post](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/44473/link-to-a-cell-in-a-google-sheets-via-url).

Comment: If you're referring to linking a table and being able to refreh, as you'd get in the Slides editor by pasting in some cells from Sheets, that's not currently supported in the Slides API. The feature request to follow is [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/64027131)